# Simplify the following: myBoolean !== false

Tags: javascript, boolean

I got the question in the title on an exam, and I find it confusing. What does the question mean and how do they want us to answer it?

Comment: it will check your myBoolean variable to boolean value as false in this case with it's datatype, that's it

Comment: Why downvote this question? Not able to answer it?

Comment: @hgoebl if there were any question at all : D

Comment: Actually if the question is *simplify* myBoolean !== false, I'm kinda stumped and would definitely love to know the simplified version  :-)

Comment: That said, this literally _can't_ be simplified. This literally checks if `myBoolean` is not equal to `false` in both ___type and value___. You can't simplify that without loosening some criteria.

Comment: @Cerbrus, you're right. It cannot be simplified without loosing the semantic that myBoolean has to be of type boolean. So `!!myBoolean` is not the answer (it came first into my mind as well).

Comment: I guess it depends on what "simplify" means, it doesn't necessarily mean "less code" or "fewer characters". It might mean more easily understood, even if that means more characters or code, e.g. `typeof myBoolean != 'boolean' || myBoolean != false`. Or the name might infer that the valule is Boolean, therefore `myBoolean != false` will do. Or not. :-/

Comment: So, @TimNguyen, does one of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

This literally *can't* be simplified.

`myBoolean !== false` checks if `myBoolean` is not equal to `false` in both ***type and value***.
You can't simplify that without loosening some criteria.

*If* you don't care about the input *type*, but just want a `true` / `false` returned from `myBoolean`, you can shorten it like this:

```
!!myBoolean
```

That forces it to a boolean value, but returns `false` for other [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values too..

Comment: Indeed. With all the subtleties of coercion, I think you're exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

If the question was looking for more of an expansion into simpler checks *than a shorter* version,

```
typeof myBoolean !== "boolean" || myBoolean != false
```

would probably be an answer.

Comment: Assuming this is a question in a test, it wouldn't actually need a point :-) except to demonstrate the understanding that the check actually has two parts (type and value).

Comment: @hgoebl - I wasn't trying to simply, merely trying to guess at what the exam question was looking for. That said, the right answer could probably be `myBoolean` assuming whoever set the exam says they are following some naming convention where the variable name myBoolean indicates a value that *is always* boolean.

Comment: @RobG true (pun intended :-)) and thanks! Have updated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is not a way to simplify:

```
!== false
```

However it is likely that the simplification they are expecting, if any, is simply:

```
true
```

There are some cases however where !== false is not the same as true. For instance, !== false would allow 0, NaN, null etc. See the comments for more details.

Comment: Not exactly, myBoolean will be false for all falsy values i.e. 0, null, NaN, undefined and false. myBoolean !== false will be false for only false. It will be true for 0, null, NaN and undefined.

Comment: As I suspected, there are intricacies to the way these things are evaluated. In the context of the original question though, how else can this be simplified?

Comment: Of that, I honestly have no idea yet :-)

Comment: My guess is that whoever set the question has failed to realise the details and is instead expecting the simplification to be as above

Comment: This is simply not true.